# specifying startup directory in console2 for tabs

Tags: windows, tabs, console2

Is there any way to open the new tab in the same directory as the existing tab ?
I am running Console2 2.xx version over Windows7 platform.

I know that we can specify default directory. But it is same for all. I am expecting unix terminal like new tab functionality, when new tab is opened in the same directory as the parent tab (from which it is opened).

Comment: Try [ConEmu](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conemu)? It has many advantages, for example you may start new tab from command line of existing one, for example `vim -new_console:h`

Answer (score 2):

You can write $PWD to a file every command you run. When you launch a new tab, use bashrc to cd to that directory written in the file.

These lines in my bashrc does the trick for me.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND echo \$PWD > /.pwd"
cd $(cat /.pwd)
```

It will mess up if you switch tabs and then launch a new tab. (Just remember to hit enter before you launch a new tab)